# What does 'significant fraction' mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning, quantifiers

Does it mean 'many' or 'small amount'? Interestingly the words significant and fraction have opposite meanings as far as I know, and yet they create a compound word.

> Significant fraction of CO2 emissions from boreal lakes derived from
>   hydrologic inorganic carbon inputs.

Comment: Replace "fraction" with "percentage" and you'll have your answer. A percentage is, essentially, a fraction. Are you certain that this sentence is correct? It seems to be missing a few words.... for example... a verb.

Answer (score 2):

[***significant***](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/significant) just means *meaningful*.
The amount to be considered *meaningful* requires additional information. For example:

> There was a significant amount/percentage of lead in the water of Flint, MI.

It was *significant* because many children got lead poisoning. But you can't say how much lead that is without additional information.

Comment: Significant is used to convey a certain message without being exact. The amount or percentage that is considered significant depends on the context. The speaker/writer may prefer not to go into the details.

Answer (score 0):

Significant denotes less of a quantity and more an importance of a quantity. Like whether something is plenty enough to be measurable, is a statistical pattern (and not a fluke), whether something is relevant and so on.

Etymologically it's apparently the combination of the Latin words for "sign" and "to make". So idk something relevant enough to create a symbol for it? Or the other way around that if people made a sign for something that denotes that it is important.

And to fracture sth. is to break something apart so a fraction is one of those parts. Usually you can also use percentages to denote that as the whole used to be 1 (or 100%) the parts are now fractions of that part/whole would literally be a mathematical fraction.

So while they can hint at quantities, significant hints at being large (enough) and fraction hinting at being small(er) than the whole, they both don't really tell you in absolute numbers whether you're dealing with something large or small so you'd need context for that.

Edit: Though when speaking about significance it's often on the lower end of the relevant or detectable scale or something that has just been realized as you're trying to establish the importance of a quantity and aren't already arguing that it's the major factor.

For example climate gasses are measured in the atmosphere as ppm or "part per million" which really doesn't sound like much, but is apparently already enough to disturb the global climate.